# flutter doctor FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Program Files\flutter\version' (OS Error: Permission denied , errno = 5)

Tags: flutter

So I recently switched to flutter and I set it up on my PC (Windows 10) and my Laptop (Ubuntu 18.04).
I only have problems on Windows 10.
Everything worked and then I got back from my vacation and tried to run my project on Win 10 and it didn't work.
Then I tried running 'flutter doctor' in the command window and not even this works.
So my question is: "Why does the 'flutter doctor' command not work?"

Down below is a picture of the command window and the crash report.

Command window:
C:\Users\Jänner>flutter doctor                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.                                                                                  Sending crash report to Google.                                                                                         Crash report sent (report ID: 7e4a9b2ece9168c9)                                                                         Crash report written to C:\Users\Jänner\flutter_03.log;                                                                 please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

Flutter Crash report file:
Flutter crash report; please file at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

### command

flutter doctor

### exception

FileSystemException: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Program Files\flutter\version' (OS Error: Zugriff verweigert
, errno = 5)

```
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:364:9)
#1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#3      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#6      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:483:5)
#7      Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:513:7)
#8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#10     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#11     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#12     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#13     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

### flutter doctor

```
[32m[✓][39m Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.615], locale de-DE)
    [32m•[39m Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at C:\Program Files\flutter
    [32m•[39m Framework revision 7a4c33425d (2 months ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
    [32m•[39m Engine revision 52c7a1e849
    [32m•[39m Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)

[33m[!][39m Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    [32m•[39m Android SDK at Z:\Java\JavaSDK
    [32m•[39m Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    [32m•[39m Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    [32m•[39m ANDROID_HOME = Z:\Java\JavaSDK
    [32m•[39m Java binary at: Z:\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    [32m•[39m Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    [31m✗[39m Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.

[32m[✓][39m Android Studio (version 3.4)
    [32m•[39m Android Studio at Z:\Android Studio
    [32m•[39m Flutter plugin version 37.0.1
    [32m•[39m Dart plugin version 183.6270
    [32m•[39m Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[33m[!][39m Connected device
    [33m![39m No devices available

[33m![39m Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk see point `2.` maybe this is a reson for your errors

Comment: Yeah that's it. Thank you mate. :D I should have seen that in the cmd but in the german version of Windows 10 in the file explorer the 'Program Files' folder is just called 'Programme'. I still wonder why I did not have those problems 1 week prior, when I installed it.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1):

It seems that installing `Flutter` in directories like `C:\Program Files\` is not ideal as it requires elevated privileges which causes some errors.

It's written as a warning in the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk).

[image]

For reference on different `Program Files` languages, you can check [this](https://www.samlogic.net/articles/program-files-folder-different-languages.htm).

[image]